# Pandas iloc and conditional sum

Tags: pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
0           1     0       1     1
1           0     1       0     1
```

I generate the sum for each column as below:

```
data.iloc[:,1:] = data.iloc[:,1:].sum(axis=0)
```

The result is:

```
0           1     1       1     2
1           1     1       1     2
```

But I only want to update values that are not zero:

```
0           1     0       1     2
1           0     1       0     2
```

As it is a large dataframe and I don't know which columns will contain zero, I am having trouble in getting the condition to work togther with the iloc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the following input:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  1  0  1  1
1  1  0  1  0  1
```

you can use the underlying numpy array and `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np
a = data.values[:, 1:]
data.iloc[:,1:] = np.where(a!=0, a.sum(0), a)
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  1  0  1  2
1  1  0  1  0  2
```